# Table headers of second table not correct with queryAllSelector

Tags: javascript, css

I am using a JavaScript snippet to show a responsive table, setting the headers on mobile via attributes. This works, but, if I use a second table with the same class, it goes all wrong on mobile (please resize your screen to see this); the headers of.

What am I doing wrong here and how can I fix this?

This is the HTML:

```
<table class="test">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Bla</th>
                                <th>Bla</th>
                                <th>Bla</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Bla</td>
                                <td>Blabla</td>
                                <td>Blablabla</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>                
                    </table>

<table class="test">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Not</th>
                                    <th>Not</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Twatwa</td>
                                    <td>Twatwa</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>                
                        </table>
```

**http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbJqVv**

Edit: after the new answer, it does show table headers on the second table now, but not the correct ones. It just puts the table headers of the first table, into the second.

Comment: how about some closing tags?

Comment: Asking the obvious question: why are you using `querySelector` rather than `querySelectorAll` for `tablebody` when each table will have it's own `tbody`

Comment: That's fixed now @Simba. The problem now is that it's setting the wrong table headers into the second table.

Comment: You have to itterate and handle each table separately. Currently you're selecting **all** headers irregardless of what table they belong to.

Comment: @Yoshi: but wouldn't that say that I have to give all tables a different class? I want it as generic as possible. How can I do that? So if someone puts a table with this class, I want it work, regardless how many tables are added.

Comment: You would first get all tables `document.querySelectorAll('.test')` then itterate over this result and apply your transformation for each table. Note that you must reference the current table instead of document. Something like `table.querySelectorAll('th')`.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either. It doesn't show any table headers at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, you need to handle each table separately. For `.querySelectorAll('.test th')` will simply give you all `th` elements, irregardless of which table they belong to.

Here's a quick example of how this could be done.

```
// for each .test
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.test'), function (table) {
  // get header contents
  var headers = [].map.call(table.querySelectorAll('th'), function (header) {
    return header.textContent.replace(/\r?\n|\r/, '');
  });

  // for each row in tbody
  [].forEach.call(table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr'), function (row) {
    // for each cell
    [].forEach.call(row.cells, function (cell, headerIndex) {
      // apply the attribute
      cell.setAttribute('data-th', headers[headerIndex]);
    });
  });
});
```

demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqEXqe

Comment: Yes yes yes, fantastic. Thanks Yoshi!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your HTML is invalid, as you are not closing any of your elements (`<tr><td></td></tr>` etc) - but that's another issue. Please practice good HTML standards.

You are not using `querySelectorAll` when selecting your table bodies, so you're only setting the attribute in the first one found.

This revised snippet should achieve what you are trying to do.

```
var headertext = [],
headers = document.querySelectorAll(".test th"),
tablerows = document.querySelectorAll(".test th"),
tablebody = document.querySelectorAll(".test tbody");

for(var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
  var current = headers[i];
  headertext.push(current.textContent.replace(/\r?\n|\r/,""));
} 

for (var tb = 0; tb < tablebody.length; tb++) {
  for (var i = 0, row; row = tablebody[tb].rows[i]; i++) {
    for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
      col.setAttribute("data-th", headertext[j]);
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: good ... i tried the exactly same .. smushed it together http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLVreL

Comment: Edit: nope, it didn't work... well, not the way it should be. If you put two tables with the same class now, but you have different table headers, it won't show the right ones. So, let's say you have 2 table headers on the first table and three table headers on the second table, it doesn't show the correct headers on mobile correctly. Check this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbJqVv